# Updating Form from backgroundworker

Tags: c#, backgroundworker, autoresetevent

I would like to update a label and delete a row from a grid from a background worker. I was reporting progress, but I noticed the report progress event does not fire immediately and found that my second report progress was executed before the first event was handled.

To wait for the event to fire, I thought of using an auto-reset event to suspend execution (waitone), with the progress event setting it to let the background worker continuing execution.

I then wondered that it might be possible that the event might fire before the waitone.

What's the best way of handling this?
Edit: following on from Patrick Tucci's suggestion, I found the following link...
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/cbd99f1f-ac56-440b-8fbd-093534e11d69/how-do-i-update-the-gui-during-execution-of-a-task?forum=csharpgeneral
In that link is this code ( I have amended a bit)...

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                var uiContext = System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
                // Start a task - this runs on the background thread...
                System.Threading.Tasks.Task task = System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("A i is " + i.ToString());
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
                        System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("B i is " + i.ToString());
                            textBox1.Text = "Delay " + i.ToString() + " has completed";
                        }, System.Threading.CancellationToken.None, System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCreationOptions.None, uiContext);

                        //textBox1.Text = "Delay " + i.ToString() + " has completed";
                    }
                },  );
                MessageBox.Show("boom!");
            }
```

However, the above isn't clear to me ...
Why is the first Task.Factory.StartNew considered a background task?
The message box statement (boom) immediately fires. Is there a way for this to not continue until the async task finishes?
And, for some reason, "Delay 1" is never displayed, i.e. A2 is not printed to debug console: only A1 B1 B2 C1 C2, etc. ?

Comment: give your any code.

Comment: With the BackgroundWorker class, to report a progress, you raise the [ProgressChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.progresschanged) event (raised in the UI thread), calling [ReportProgress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.reportprogress). Enable this feature by setting [WorkerReportsProgress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.workerreportsprogress) to `true`, before calling `BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync`.

Comment: BGW uses BeginInvoke to report progress, you can't guess when the invoke target is going to execute.  Can take a while when the UI thread is busy with something else, not excluding previous invoke requests.  That should and must never be a problem.  But no, there is no way that these invokes can execute out-of-order, the underlying queue that stores these invoke requests is strictly ordered and protected with a mutex so always thread-safe.  So you're doing it wrong, somehow, we can't see it.

Comment: I would personally look into the `async`/`await` pattern using `Task`. Personally, this programming pattern seems much more intuitive than `BackgroundWorker`.

Comment: Ok that task looks promising, but I think I might need Framework 4.6: It's possible  that 4.5 is my target. I have updated my main post with another thought based on this.

Answer (score 0):

OK, this was a failure of mine to understand how the autoresetevent works.

Before the loop in the background worker starts, I should **AE.Reset** anyway. Doing this means the next **WaitOne** will cause the worker to sleep.

In the loop, I should **ReportProgress** as usual, followed by the **WaitOne**. The **WaitOne** causes the worker to sleep, but only if the AE has been **Reset**. If the AE has been **Set**, the worker will continue as usual.

In the **ProgressChanged** event, I should update the usual Gui controls, followed by **AE.Set** in order to allow the sleeping worker at **WaitOne** state to continue.

If for some reason the **AE.WaitOne** is executed AFTER the **AE.Set**, the worker does not wait for anything.

Finally, whether the worker waited or not, the AE is automatically reset, meaning that **WaitOne** will once again sleep.

Basically ...
Doing **Reset** causes the next **WaitOne** to sleep.
Doing **Set** releases thread at **WaitOne**.
If nothing at **WaitOne**, Set immediately releases the **NEXT** **WaitOne**.
Doing **WaitOne** automatically **Resets**.

All a bit confusing, and the documentation is not the best. But I got it.

I will stick to background worker, because they are in my opinion far more simpler tasks.